# How to add checkbox values to an array in AngularJS?

Tags: arrays, angularjs, checkbox

Someone help me please!
Lets say I have an a list of a checkboxes, each checkbox have an ID.
I would like to $scope an array with checked checkboxes IDs.

```
<div ng-app="myapp">
<div ng-controller="ctrlParent">
    <table>           
    <tr ng-repeat="(key, value) in providers">
        <td><input type="checkbox" ng-model="ids[value.Id]">  {{value}} </td>
    </tr>            
    </table>
    {{ids}}
</div>
```

And my controller:

```
var app = angular.module('myapp',[]);

app.controller('ctrlParent',function($scope){
    $scope.providers = [{Id:5},{Id:6},{Id:8},{Id:10}];
    $scope.ids = {};
});
```

Now my array output (if all check boxes are checked) is: {"5":true,"6":true,"8":true,"10":true}

And I would like: [{Id:5},{Id:6},{Id:8},{Id:10}]

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29078425/whats-a-good-way-of-adding-and-remove-object-details-to-an-array-when-a-checkbo/29079142#29079142) out.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

this is a possible solution:

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="ids[$index]" ng-true-value="
        {{value}}" ng-false-value="{{undefined}}"/>{{value}}
```

In this way, you will have an array of objects, because you are assigning `ids[$index] = value`.

There is a cons however: when you double check a checkbox, you will have an empty element in the array.

```js
var app = angular.module('myapp', []);

app.controller('ctrlParent', function($scope) {
  $scope.providers = [{
    Id: 5
  }, {
    Id: 6
  }, {
    Id: 8
  }, {
    Id: 10
  }];
  $scope.ids = [];

  $scope.$watchCollection('ids', function(newVal) {
    for (var i = 0; i < newVal.length; ++i) {

      console.log(newVal[i]);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myapp">
  <div ng-controller="ctrlParent">
    <table>
      <tr ng-repeat="(key,value) in providers">
        <td>
          <input type="checkbox" ng-model="ids[$index]" ng-true-value="{{value}}" ng-false-value="{{undefined}}" />{{value}}
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>{{ids}}</div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/b9jj0re2/3/

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="ids[$index]" ng-true-value="{{value}}" >
```

Addign the ng-true-value directive will solve the problem 
and in controller change the ids from object to array

[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/EBqaRDP22bLVPVFNOTkc)

Comment: C'mon, it was the same solution I provided, 10 minutes earlier

Comment: down for same solution as above